# Best way to get all possible php versions that can be installed

Tags: php, grep, version, apt

I'm working on a way to select your preferred PHP version for the VestaCP Installation script. What I intend is for the script to detect which versions of PHP are available as options to install, and allow the person installing VestaCP to choose which available version they want to install, based on the available versions from the repos on their systems at the time of install.

The command I'm issuing to get JUST the version numbers for php works fine:

`apt-cache showpkg php | grep -A 20 'Reverse Provides' | grep -P '^php' | colrm 7 | sort -u`

`apt-cache showpkg` gives me ALL available versions (not just candidates)

`grep -A 20` gives me the 20 (arbitrary number large enough) lines from the Reverse Provides section, getting rid of the rest I don't care about

`grep -P` gives me only the lines from that section that start with php

`colrm` cuts off everything except the actual version numbers

`sort` gives me only unique values (since multiple repos offer the same php versions)

The result is exactly as desired:

```
php5.6
php7.0
php7.1
php7.2
php7.3
php7.4
```

My question: Is there a better way to do this? Seems like a lot of pipes and a lot of steps to accomplish such a simple task. It will be almost exclusively Ubuntu/Debian/CentOS/RHEL systems that this will be running on. .

Comment: I understand that I'll have to find a YUM equivalent for CentOS/RHEL, but I want to see if there are any better options before I spend the time doing that.

Comment: I'm just going to point you to the [official install script](https://github.com/serghey-rodin/vesta/blob/master/install/vst-install.sh) which has a lot of the cross-platform logic that you are looking for already worked out.

Comment: I'm well aware of that script. It doesn't have ANY logic related to figuring out which PHP versions are available from the repos on each specific machine. At best it gets me whether it's Ubuntu/Debian/CentOS/RHEL. Nothing beyond that, which is why I'm writing my own.

Comment: For reference, here's a thread I recently posted about BYPASSING that script to install specific PHP versions: https://forum.vestacp.com/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=19941  I'm looking to step it up a few notches from just being a step-by-step guide to being a full script that will do it all for you (and more).